# How to access Global.asax variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, global-variables

I am unsuccessful in accessing application state variable in javascript.

I declared the app state variable as,

```
Application["MYVAR"] ="My Variable";
```

JS:

```
var _myjsvar = <%='Application["MYVAR"]'%>
alert(_myjsvar);
```

But I don't get the value in JS alert. Any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as long as it is in a page executed by server ( ex :your aspx view etc..)

```
var _myjsvar = '<%= Application["MYVAR"] %>';
alert(_myjsvar);
```

If it is a razor view where you want to access the Application variable, you can do this.

```
<script>
    var _myjsvar = "@HttpContext.Current.Application["MYVAR"]";
    alert(_myjsvar);
</script>
```

Comment: I am dealing with MVC view not aspx

Comment: In this case, the JS variable is loaded first and then applicaton variable. I get the alert value as undefined and then the value is loaded. Did you get what I mean?

Comment: As long as you set the application variable value, We should be able to read it. What problem are you running into ? Are you trying to read the value even before you set it ?